# Can't get jq to recognize an array within a json file

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I have a json file that I use for work that I need to parse that is in the following format:

```
(^)#(^)#(^)#(^)bminter@ubuntu:~$ cat jqtest
{
   "files":[
      {
         "BLOCK1":{
            "SUBBLOCK1":{
               "akey1":"avalue1",
               "bkey1":"bvalue1",
               "ckey1":"cvalue1"
            },
            "dkey1":"dvalue1",
            "key":"evalue1"
         }
      },
      {
         "BLOCK-2":{
            "SUBBLOCK2":{
               "akey2":"avalue2",
               "bkey2":"bvalue2"
            },
            "ckey2":"cvalue2",
            "key":"dvalue2"
         }
      },
      {
         "BLOCK-A":{
            "SUBBLOCK2":{
               "akey2":"avalue2",
               "bkey2":"bvalue2"
            },
            "ckey2":"cvalue2",
            "key":"dvalue2"
         }
      }],
   "NOBLOCK":"value",
   "key":"NOBLOCKvalue"
}
```

So it's an array nested within a json file.  `jq .[] jqtest` gives me everything in the file.  Even the data outside the array.  Except, outside the array, I'm only given the values not the keys:

```
(^)#(^)#(^)#(^)bminter@ubuntu:~$ jq .[] jqtest
[
  {
    "BLOCK1": {
      "SUBBLOCK1": {
        "akey1": "avalue1",
        "bkey1": "bvalue1",
        "ckey1": "cvalue1"
      },
      "dkey1": "dvalue1",
      "key": "evalue1"
    }
  },
  {
    "BLOCK-2": {
      "SUBBLOCK2": {
        "akey2": "avalue2",
        "bkey2": "bvalue2"
      },
      "ckey2": "cvalue2",
      "key": "dvalue2"
    }
  },
  {
    "BLOCK-A": {
      "SUBBLOCK2": {
        "akey2": "avalue2",
        "bkey2": "bvalue2"
      },
      "ckey2": "cvalue2",
      "key": "dvalue2"
    }
  }
]
"value"
"NOBLOCKvalue"
(^)#(^)#(^)#(^)bminter@ubuntu:~$
```

Beyond that I can't access any block inside the array:

```
(^)#(^)#(^)#(^)bminter@ubuntu:~$ jq '.[].BLOCK1' jqtest
jq: error (at jqtest:36): Cannot index array with string "BLOCK1"
(^)#(^)#(^)#(^)bminter@ubuntu:~$ jq '.[].BLOCK-2' jqtest
jq: error (at jqtest:36): Cannot index array with string "BLOCK"
(^)#(^)#(^)#(^)bminter@ubuntu:~$ jq '.[].BLOCK-A' jqtest
jq: error: A/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.[].BLOCK-A          
jq: 1 compile error
(^)#(^)#(^)#(^)bminter@ubuntu:~$
```

How do I access the array?

Comment: The array is sitting in the `files` property... access the `files` property... `.files`

Comment: `jq '.files | .[] | .BLOCK1' jqtest` works.  `jq '.files | .[] | .BLOCK-2' jqtest` gives this error: `jq: error (at jqtest:36): null (null) and number (2) cannot be subtracted`.  `jq '.files | .[] | .BLOCK-A' jqtest` gives this error: `jq: error: A/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1: /  .files | .[] | .BLOCK-A  / jq: 1 compile error`.

Comment: When using the `.name` syntax, the names must follow the usual identifier naming rules found in most programming languages. `-` is not a valid identifier character, you have to use the object index syntax: `."BLOCK-A"` or `.["BLOCK-A"]`.

Comment: This works!  Thanks Jeff.

Answer (score 1):

The array of objects with non-uniform keys is making things a little tricky here.  Once you've gotten past `.files` you need to start using [Array Iteration `[]`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#.[]?) to access those elements and then use object operations like [`keys`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#keys,keys_unsorted) to go deeper.

Here is a function which may help in this situation.  It scans `.files` for an object with a key matching the specified key and then returns the corresponding value:

```
def getfile($k): .files[] | select(keys[] | .==$k) | .[$k];
```

If `jqtest` contains the sample data the command

```
$ jq -M '
def getfile($k): .files[] | select(keys[] | .==$k) | .[$k];
getfile("BLOCK1").SUBBLOCK1.akey1
' jqtest
```

Returns

```
"avalue1"
```

Another approach is to use a function to convert `.files[]` into a more useful form.  e.g.

```
$ jq -M '
def files: reduce .files[] as $f ({}; ($f|keys[0]) as $k | .[$k] = $f[$k]) ;
files 
' jqtest
```

this returns a more uniform structure without arrays

```
{
  "BLOCK1": {
    "SUBBLOCK1": {
      "akey1": "avalue1",
      "bkey1": "bvalue1",
      "ckey1": "cvalue1"
    },
    "dkey1": "dvalue1",
    "key": "evalue1"
  },
  "BLOCK-2": ...
```

so with it you can write

```
files.BLOCK1.SUBBLOCK1
```

to obtain

```
{
  "akey1": "avalue1",
  "bkey1": "bvalue1",
  "ckey1": "cvalue1"
}
```

Note that jq will re-evaluate the `files` function with each use so the following form may be more practical:

```
  files as $files
| $files.BLOCK1.SUBBLOCK1
```

If you find this representation useful you may want to skip the function and instead just start your filter with

```
.files = reduce .files[] as $f ({}; ($f|keys[0]) as $k | .[$k] = $f[$k])
```

e.g.

```
$ jq -M '
.files = reduce .files[] as $f ({}; ($f|keys[0]) as $k | .[$k] = $f[$k])
# more stuff goes here
' jqtest
```

which converts your input to

```
{
  "files": {
    "BLOCK1": {
      "SUBBLOCK1": {
        "akey1": "avalue1",
        "bkey1": "bvalue1",
        "ckey1": "cvalue1"
      },
      "dkey1": "dvalue1",
      "key": "evalue1"
    },
    "BLOCK-2": {
      "SUBBLOCK2": {
        "akey2": "avalue2",
        "bkey2": "bvalue2"
      },
      "ckey2": "cvalue2",
      "key": "dvalue2"
    },
    "BLOCK-A": {
      "SUBBLOCK2": {
        "akey2": "avalue2",
        "bkey2": "bvalue2"
      },
      "ckey2": "cvalue2",
      "key": "dvalue2"
    }
  },
  "NOBLOCK": "value",
  "key": "NOBLOCKvalue"
}
```

making whatever else you need to do after that easier

Comment: This looks like a really interesting approach and I wish I understood it more but I can't get past the first statement.  `def getfile($k): .files[] | select(keys[] | .==$k) | .[$k];` gives me the following error: `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('`

Comment: try `jq 'def getfile($k): .files[] | select(keys[] | .==$k) | .[$k]; getfile("BLOCK1").SUBBLOCK1.akey1' jqtest` or consider placing the filter into a file `filter.jq` and running `jq -f filter.jq jqtest`