# How do I use jq to single out a specific element in a json array whose order keeps changing?

Tags: arrays, json, scripting, filtering, jq

I have a file with the following format:

{

```
   "files":[
      {
         "BLOCK1":{
            "SUBBLOCK1":{
               "akey1":"avalue1",
               "bkey1":"bvalue1",
               "ckey1":"cvalue1"
            },
            "dkey1":"dvalue1",
            "key":"evalue1"
         }
      },
      {
         "BLOCK-2":{
            "SUBBLOCK2":{
               "akey2":"avalue2",
               "bkey2":"bvalue2"
            },
            "ckey2":"cvalue2",
            "key":"dvalue2"
         }
      },
      {
         "BLOCK-A":{
            "SUBBLOCKA":{
               "akeyA":"avalueA",
               "bkeyA":"bvalueA"
            },
            "ckeyA":"cvalueA",
            "key":"dvalueA"
         }
      }],
   "NOBLOCK":"value",
   "key":"NOBLOCKvalue"
}
```

I'm using the following the jq statement to isolate "bvalueA":

```
value=$(jq -r '.files | .[2] | .["BLOCK-A"].SUBBLOCKA.bkeyA' jqtest)
```

Which works just fine.  But the file changes order every night.  So BLOCK-A might be element 0 one night, 1 the next, so on and so forth.  How can I modify jq to always drill down to BLOCK-A no matter which element in the array it is?

Answer (score 2):

This might be the least-keystrokes solution:

```
 .files[]."BLOCK-A"//empty|.SUBBLOCKA.bkeyA
```

If there is a possibility that there is more than one "BLOCK-A" element, and if you want to ensure that all but the first will be ignored when that is the case, then you could wrap the above in a call to `first/1`, assuming your version of jq has it:  first( ... )

Using `first` in this manner also yields a more efficient solution.

Comment: I was hoping you'll  answer here.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`select()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select(boolean_expression)):

```
jq -r '.files[]|select(.["BLOCK-A"])|.["BLOCK-A"].SUBBLOCKA.bkeyA'
```

or [`map()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#map(x),map_values(x)):

```
jq -r '.files|map(.["BLOCK-A"]//empty)[].SUBBLOCKA.bkeyA'
```

Answer (score 0):

The alternative approach with `has()` function:

```
jq -r '.files[] | if (has("BLOCK-A")) then .["BLOCK-A"].SUBBLOCKA.bkeyA else empty end' jqtest
bvalueA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an solution based on [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46305351/8379597) to your earlier question:

```
$ jq -M '

def getfile($k): .files[] | select(keys[] == $k) | .[$k];

getfile("BLOCK-A").SUBBLOCKA.bkeyA

' jqtest
```

With the sample data provided the output is:

```
"bvalueA"
```